# como resolver este problema de JS? posicionar las rocas en el planeta marte

Tags: javascript

Misión del Rover de Marte

Tu tarea:

> Formas parte del equipo que explora Marte enviando vehículos controlados a distancia a la superficie del planeta. Desarrolla un software que traduzca los comandos enviados desde la Tierra a instrucciones que sean entendidas por el rover.

Requisitos:

- Se le da el punto inicial de partida (x,y) de un rover y la dirección (N,S,E,W) a la que está orientado.
- El rover recibe una colección de comandos. (Por ejemplo) FFRRFFFRL
- El rover puede moverse hacia adelante (f).
- El rover puede moverse a la izquierda/derecha (l,r).
- Supongamos que estamos en un planeta realmente extraño que es cuadrado. 200x200 por ejemplo :)
- Implementar la detección de obstáculos antes de cada movimiento a un nuevo cuadrado. Si una determinada secuencia de comandos encuentra un obstáculo, el rover se mueve hasta el último punto posible, aborta la secuencia e informa del obstáculo.

Tengo el ejercicio casi completo, me falta posicionar los obstáculos dentro del planeta, e echo un array de objetos con las rocas y su posición en el planeta pero no consigo mapearlas correctamente para que se coloquen y se vean en el DOM, el resultado es undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="cotainer">
            <div class="image-astronaut">
                <div class="cont-img">
                    <img id="astronaut" src="./images/astronauta.png" style="width: 50px;" alt="">
                    <div id="astronaut-paragraph" class="paragraph" style="visibility: hidden;">
                        Hi I'm George Clooney and I'm still lost in space.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="container-mars">
                <div id="rover" style="visibility: hidden;"><img class="img-rover" src="./images/rover-lunar.png"></div>
                <div id="rock" style="width: 50px;"><img src="./images/rock.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-spacecraft">
                <div class="cont-img">
                    <img id="spacecraft" src="./images/nave.png" style="width: 250px;">
                    <div id="spacecraft-paragraph" class="paragraph-spacecraft">
                        Today is a good day to conquer the earth!!!!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-nasa">
        <img src="./images/logo-nasa.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
        <h2>Panel Control</h2>
        <img src="./images/logo-nasa.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
    </div>
    <div class="container-panel-control">

        <div class="panel-control">
            <div id="container-input-initial">
                <input id="inputX" type="number" min="0" max="36" placeholder="0..36">
                <input id="inputY" type="number" min="0" max="36" placeholder="0..36">
                <button id="buttonPosition" class="btn btn-success" style="height: 29px;
                width: 107px;
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;">set position</button>
            </div>
            <div id="container-input-movement" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <input id="inputM" class="input-start" type="text">
                <button id="buttonStart" class="btn btn-success" style="height: 29px;
                width: 107px;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;">start</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="instructions">
            <h3>Instructions</h3>
            <p>The planet Mars has dimensions of 400x400 for better visibility.<br> The rover has dimensions of 40x40.<br> To visualize the rover you have to enter the starting coordinates, and then you can give movement commands.<br> The rover cannot leave
                the planet, and any command to move it out of the planet will not be executed and an alert will be triggered.<br> The images contain hidden surprises. <br> Enjoy the mission.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>


let rover = document.getElementById("rover");
let moveLeft = 0;
let moveFront = 0;
let buttonStart = document.getElementById("buttonStart");
let buttonPosition = document.getElementById("buttonPosition");
let movements;
let planetSizeX = 400;
let planetsizeY = 400;
let roverSizeX = 40;
let roverSizeY = 40;
let roverCrashed;

let positionRocks = [{
    r1: { x: 60, y: 10 },
    r2: { x: 150, y: 300 },
    r3: { x: 320, y: 120 }
}];



positionRocks.map((rock) => (
    rock = document.getElementById("rock"),
    document.getElementById("container-mars").innerHTML = rock.r1,
    document.getElementById("container-mars").innerHTML = rock.r2,
    document.getElementById("container-mars").innerHTML = rock.r3
))

buttonStart.addEventListener("click", () => {
    roverCrashed = false;
    let inputM = document.getElementById("inputM");
    movements = inputM.value.toUpperCase();

    [...movements].forEach((step) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!roverCrashed) {
                MoveRover(step);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
    document.getElementById("inputM").value = "";
});

buttonPosition.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let initialX = document.getElementById("inputX").value;
    let initialY = document.getElementById("inputY").value;
    moveLeft = initialX * 10;
    rover.style.marginLeft = moveLeft + "px";
    moveFront = initialY * 10;
    rover.style.marginTop = moveFront + "px";
    rover.style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("container-input-movement").style.visibility =
        "visible";
});

function MoveRover(commands) {
    switch (commands) {
        case "L":
            MoveLeft();
            break;

        case "R":
            MoveRight();
            break;

        case "F":
            MoveFront();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

function MoveLeft() {
    if (moveLeft > 0) {
        moveLeft -= 10;
        rover.style.marginLeft = moveLeft + "px";
    } else {
        roverCrashed = true;
        alert(
            "The rover cannot execute these movements because it would leave the planet."
        );
    }
}

function MoveRight() {
    if (moveLeft < planetSizeX - roverSizeX) {
        moveLeft += 10;
        rover.style.marginLeft = moveLeft + "px";
    } else {
        roverCrashed = true;
        alert(
            "The rover cannot execute these movements because it would leave the planet."
        );
    }
}

function MoveFront() {
    if (moveFront < planetsizeY - roverSizeY) {
        moveFront += 10;
        rover.style.marginTop = moveFront + "px";
    } else {
        roverCrashed = true;
        alert(
            "The rover cannot execute these movements because it would leave the planet."
        );

    }
}




document
    .getElementById("astronaut")
    .addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverAstronaut);
document
    .getElementById("astronaut")
    .addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOutAstronaut);

function mouseOverAstronaut() {
    document.getElementById("astronaut-paragraph").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOutAstronaut() {
    document.getElementById("astronaut-paragraph").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

document
    .getElementById("spacecraft")
    .addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverSpacecraft);
document
    .getElementById("spacecraft")
    .addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOutSpacecraft);

function mouseOverSpacecraft() {
    document.getElementById("spacecraft-paragraph").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOutSpacecraft() {
    document.getElementById("spacecraft-paragraph").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: Te faltó indicar dentro del post cuál es tu pregunta. Puedes [edit] y formular tu pregunta. No sabemos cuál es el problema

Comment: No combines `addEventListener()` con `onclick`, en el fragmento de código se obtiene un error porque la variable `valor` no está definida. Crea una sola función para hacer lo que necesites.

Comment: Además, parece que puedes obtener varias instrucciones, por lo que debes recorrer cada caracter para saber a dónde mover.

Comment: podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como hacerlo, e conseguido que se mueva pero solo un movimiento y no varias instrucciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba este snippet, hay los cambios que te sugieren en los comentarios y alguno más.

```js
let rover = document.getElementById("rover");
let mLeft = 0;
let mRight = 0;
let mTop = 0;
let boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var valor

boton.addEventListener("click", () => {

  let input = document.getElementById("input");
  valor = input.value;
  MoveRover()
  // alert("El valor del campo es:" + valor);

});

function MoveRover() {
  if (valor === "l") {
    MoveLeft()
  } else if (valor === "r") {
    MoveRight()
  } else if (valor === "f") {
    MoveTop()
  }
}

function MoveLeft() {
  mLeft += 1;
  rover.style.marginLeft = mLeft + "px"
}

function MoveRight() {
  mRight += 1;
  rover.style.marginRight = mRight + "px"
}


function MoveTop() {
  mTop += 1;
  rover.style.marginTop = mTop + "px"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container-input">
      <input id="input" type="text">
      <button id="boton">click</button>
    </div>

    <div id="container-mars">
      <div id="rover">a</div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Aunque solo parece funcionar lo de ir hacia abajo (le he puesto una `a` al div para verlo, supongo que con tu css se apreciaria mejor).

**Explicación de los cambios**

1. Se ha agregado la variable global `valor` para que se pueda usar en todas las funciones

```
var valor
```

2. Se ha cambiado su asignación dentro del evento capturado `click`, cambiando simplemente su valor:

```
valor = input.value
```

3. Se ha agregado la llamada a la función `MoveRover()` dentro del evento capturado y se ha suprimido del elemento con `id="boton"` para evitar dobles llamadas al mismo evento que no estarian sincronizadas seguramente.

Prueba y verás que al menos cuando pones la `f` en el snippet y pulsas varias veces el botón la `a` se mueve hacia abajo.  El resto de movimientos no funcionan, pero quizás es por la falta del css, compruébalo y arréglalo.

Comment: se mueve en todas la direcciones, gracias